# Ubuntu Random Freeze and then Restart

Tags: 12.04, freeze, restart

I'm on the verge of throwing my computer out my window.  Ubuntu keeps randomly freezing and restarting itself.  When it freezes, I can't move the mouse and it won't respond to any keyboard input.  However, if I spam a lot of keys, it doesn't restart, it just stays stuck.  It won't respond to REISUB either.

I can't find any correlation to what I'm doing and why it's restarting.  I didn't notice anything that struck me in the logs.  If you'd like me to post a specific log, please let me know.  I suspect it may be over heating but whenever I monitor the temps via monitors and via nvidia they don't spike or increase more than five degrees.

The only programs I have install are relating to Ruby on Rails / Sublime Text / Chrome.  I reinstalled everything, and noticed no problems.  I left my computer running for four or so hours and it stayed on.  Then I went through and finished RoR, it all ran.  I added Guard and Zeus.  Then about 20 minutes after that it restarted.  I think this was random again?  Or at least I couldn't find a reason why Zeus / Guard would cause a restart?

```
Ubuntu: 12.04
Rails: 3.2.11
Ruby: 1.9.3
Graphics: GTS 450 (Nvidia) 
Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 
Memory: 2GB
OS: 32 Bit
Space: 30GB
NVIDIA Driver Version: 295.40
```

In order to get rails working, I did follow this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705351/rails-typhoeus-curl-trouble/12709051#12709051

I've read through this thread but it doesn't produce a viable solution:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/993187

Suggestions?  Ideas?  Sympathy or pity?

Comment: I have been running it all day today, not running my rails server, guard, or Zeus and it hasn't crashed.  Has anyone ever heard of a RoR server causing a crash or a gem?

Comment: Ubuntu hasn't been restarting if I don't run anything that plays videos or music for an extended time.  I'm alright if I watch a rails cast or a short YouTube video but I can't stream Pandora for hours. - Still looking for a solution!